# Proving a matrix has non trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

A & B are 3x3 matrices and
$$\ A^{T} = -A $$

I need to prove that

$\ (A^{2}B)x = 0 $ has a non trivial solution.

so I understand that

$\ |A| = |A^{T}| = |-A| = -1^{n}|A| = 0 $ because n=3. and from that I conclude that A is not invertible and if $\ A^T = -A $ it must have tr(A) = 0 but i'm stuck and would love get a hint.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$det(A) = 0 \Rightarrow det(A^2B)= 0 $$

As $det(A^2B) = 0 \Rightarrow rank(A^2B) < 3 \Rightarrow$ the columns of $A^2B$ are linearly dependent $\Rightarrow$ there is a non-zero vector $x = (x_1\; x_2\; x_3)^T$ such that $A^2B x = 0$.

Comment: This is the dimension of the column space of the matrix.

Comment: @Yarden Gur: You can skip the part with the rank if you know that $det(A^2B)= 0$ implies that the columns of the matrix $A^2B$ are linearly dependent. I just pointed it out as you may know the rank-nullity theorem: $rank(A^2B) + dim(ker A^2B) = 3$ in your case. So, $dim(ker A^2B) > 0$ which mean as well that there are non-trivial solutions to $A^2Bx=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\det(A)=0$,$$\det(A^2B)=\det(A)^2\det(B)=0,$$and therefore, $(A^2B).x=0$ has a non-trivial solution.